# CloudWatch metric aggregation - cannot drop base metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup CloudWatch agent in AWS to report CPU & memory utilization for certain group of processes (Tanium agents specifically) to understand their influence on servers performance.

I used procstat plugin in config to gather metrics for processes with Tanium in their name/path and it worked well. Next I defined aggregation_dimension and can see aggregate value in CloudWatch - all good. However I need to get rid of the base metrics now I get aggregate as for hundreds of servers I cannot keep individual Tanium processes metrics as it will get very expensive. I only want one aggregate CPU usage per each server instance.

Tried all forms of "drop_original_metrics" property coimbinations ("drop_original_metrics": [ "cpu_usage"  ] and also tried with [ "procstat_cpu_usage"  ]) but this does not have any effect. Alle teh time all processes metrics are published despite all my efforts.

What am I doing wrong? Please help as docuemntation is poor and could not find examples doing exactly what I need. Thank you!

Cloudwatch agent config:

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
        "run_as_user": "cwagent"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "aggregation_dimensions" : [
             ["InstanceId","ProcstatGroup"],
             ["ProcstatGroup"]
        ],
        "metrics_collected": {
            "procstat": [
                {
                        "append_dimensions": { "ProcstatGroup": "Tanium" },
                        "pattern": "[Tt]anium",
                        "measurement": [ "cpu_usage" ],
                        "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
                        "aggregation_statistic_functions": [["Sum"]],
                        "drop_original_metrics": [ "cpu_usage"  ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```